# cambiar el color de una letra con un click y luego con otro click volver al color que estaba

Tags: javascript

quiero que al hacer un click en el texto cambie de color amarrilo a verde, y luego al hacer click nuevamente que cambie de verde a amarillo

```js
var h1 = document.getElementById('h1');



if (h1.classList.contains('yellow') === true) {
    h1.addEventListener('click', () => {
        h1.classList.replace('yellow', 'blue')
    })
} else {}

if (h1.classList.contains('blue') === true) {
    h1.addEventListener('click', () => {
        h1.classList.replace('blue', 'yellow')
    })

} else {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Va bien, sin embargo podría simplificarse mas procediendo de esta forma:

- Al título declarale un color desde CSS para que al inicio sea por naturaleza de color verde
- Obtienes al h1 y lo asignas a una variable
- A la variable donde almacenaste al h1 le das un listener en el evento click
- A la misma variable le indicas que hará por medio de `classList` un toggle con lo cual si tiene la clase cambiante le dará dicho color y si no se la quitará y quedará con la clase que recién tenía donde es de color verde

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
      <style>
        .titulo {
          color: green;
        }
        .cambiante {
          color: yellow;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1 class="titulo">Texto cambiante</h1>
    <script>
        let titulo = document.querySelector(".titulo")
        
        titulo.addEventListener("click", () => {
          titulo.classList.toggle("cambiante")
        })
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Referencias**

- [Método toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)